# Import sql dump

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import an sql dump into mysql. I selected in command prompt the directory where the file is and I'm using the following command( from inside the file's directory):

```
mysql -u root -p password database < file.sql
```

It doesn't show any specific detail regarding this, it just shows the list of all the options I have, like in a help. I'm not an advanced user of mysql, maybe you have an idea why it isn't working. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the password immediately after `-p`. Also, you misspelled `mysql`:

```
mysql -u root -ppassword database < file.sql
```

Comment: yea thanks. that was it :) seems to work. I misspelled mysql only here, it's fine in command prompt, sorry.