# Is there any ways to import MySQL database from Windows to Linux?

Tags: mysql, linux

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. I expected to import a sql file that exported from Windows machine to my Linux PC. I did it by command: `mysql> source /path/to/mysqlfile/name.sql;` After importing completed, I realized that all table's name in my database are lowercase and my app cannot get data from these( I rename one table to uppercase to test and it worked well). So my question is: is there any ways to auto import database from Windows to Linux (table name change from lowercase to uppercase)? Because it is very waste time if we have hundreds tables and have to rename them manually.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import sql dump](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066872/import-sql-dump)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving MySql from windows server to linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818106/moving-mysql-from-windows-server-to-linux).

Comment: I read both of thread, however they did help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `lower_case_table_names` option to 1 in your mysqld config file, which will cause mysql server to match object names case-insensitively. Have a look at [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) article

Comment: Many thanks, after set `lower_case_table_names = 1` and restart MySQL I check by this command: `mysqladmin -u root -p variables` and recognized the change in my database:`|lower_case_table_names                            | 1 `. Finally, I rebuild my project and everything run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Import database for xampp Without using database password [enter link description here](http://solveubuntu.blogspot.in/p/server.html)

:- $ su

:- $ user password ********

:- # /opt/lampp/bin/mysql>mysql -uroot -p database_name < database path